# How to access user local profile using javascript?

Tags: javascript, user-profile

I am hunting to access user local profile such as `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local`. So far, no luck but I want to hear from experts that how can I access user local profile?

**Update**

If I tried with following code snippet it created at `C:\Users\username\Desktop` but when I tried with `\\AppData\\Local\\ABC.txt` it prompts `Path not found`

```
function createFile(){
    var fileObj = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var fileName = "ABC.txt";

    if(fileObj.FileExists(fileName)){
        //empty file
        var emptyFile = fileObj.OpenTextFile(fileName, 2, false);
        emptyFile.close();
        //write to file
        var openFile = fileObj.OpenTextFile(fileName, 2, false);
        openFile.WriteLine("Created from JS");
        openFile.close();       
    }
    else{
        //create new file
        var newfile = fileObj.CreateTextFile(fileName,false);
        //write to file
        newfile.WriteLine("Created from JS");
        newfile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `\\AppData` would be a network share.  Did you try `%appdata%\ABC.txt` or `%localappdata%\ABC.txt`?

Comment: I need to reach local folder included in appdata

Comment: That's what `%localappdata%` is.  Whether or not it works in this situation I have no idea, hence comments and not answers...

Answer (score 0):

AppData contains data folder which is, by default, inaccessible to other users.

you need to change permission for user to access AppData.

Comment: I am trying to let the user create a txt file. And I think this is only possible to create at appdata\local because it is local directory for only that user.

Comment: see if user have permission to write inside folder?